# New Meta sites out of order in /sites

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stackauth

I don't know if this is by design, but the ServerFault and SuperUser Meta sites don't follow their main sites in the response for the `sites` API route. Having `linked_meta` sites follow their main (`normal`) sites makes grouping sites much easier, so I'm hoping this will be fixed.

Also, their icon URLs currently return 404s, but I'm guessing that's only temporary.

Comment: code poet's answer is correct.  This by design behavior, the ordering of /sites is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The appearance order of sites in /sites is non-determinant and should not be relied upon.

On a personal note, using order of appearance as a grouping seems more complex than simply using a meta. modifier

I am certain that you can depend on the api.xxx.com/api.meta.xxx.com pattern and can assemble your grouping or relations.

And, no, i am no authority, but i do play one in my own mind. at night. when i am staying at a holiday inn express.

Comment: Do you always sleep with a gun under your pillow?

Comment: Holiday Inn Express? A programmer???

Comment: @far - i guess you need to be a yank to get that one. http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q="But+I+did+stay+at+a+Holiday+Inn+Express+last+night"

Comment: me no likey two-pass. thanks for the answer, though =)

Comment: @can - if you reverse the api_endpoint and sort (or do it in place) you will get what you want quite easily without having to parse the strings.

Comment: @Code, my comment was a James Bond reference, but I didn't get the holiday in thing anyway.

Comment: @code: I ended up comparing site_urls and moving linked_metas next to their main sites. I wanted to keep the main sites in response order.